# Как добавить в ListBox Item, в роли которого выступает Page (страница с xaml разметкой)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Использую WPF.

Есть ListBox размером 100 в ширину, 100 в длину. Есть элемент Page, который имеет размер 20 в ширину, 100 в длину (на этой странице, присутствует такие элементы как: Image, TextBlock и тд.).

Логика работы.
Подключаюсь к БД, беру от туда информацию о пользователе, запихиваю её на Page, а потом я этот Page должен вставить в ListBox. (то есть я должен вставить Page в ListBox, потом снова загнать информацию в Page и снова добавить его в ListBox)

Вопрос: как мне добавить Page в качестве элемента ListBox?

Comment: Посоветую использовать `Binding`.

Comment: А где именно? Нельзя передать в binding страницу

Comment: Не могу привести пример, т.к. нет IDE под руками.

Comment: жаль, пойду тогда поищу информацию про Binding

Comment: Вы только усложнили себе задачу используя Page. Создайте usercontrol, и выставите его в качестве header'а у listboxitem.

Comment: А вообще это делается через HierarchicalDataTemplate. https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/14.8.php

Comment: Это не совсем то. Я сейчас делаю чат (для себя), а именно левое меню, где распологаются контакты, здесь HierarchicalDataTemplate не подходит http://store-images.s-microsoft.com/image/apps.60082.14473651905739879.bfe5696c-3029-4573-b99c-50754db335e8.cfbf1d62-8493-484b-b889-6fc0a386078b